# How to resolve upgrade exception in guidewire

Tags: guidewire

When I started the server in guidewire CC I got this error.

com.guidewire.pl.system.exception.UpgradeException: Encryption has been removed or changed, but the OldEncryption plugin is not defined. Please see your documentation for details on encryption upgrade.

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the database you are connecting to is a newer or differently encrypted version that what the Guidewire application codebase you are running is expecting.

What is the value of `CurrentEncryptionPlugin` in your `config.xml` file?

```
  <!-- The name of the current encryption plugin. -->
  <param name="CurrentEncryptionPlugin" value="AESEncrypter"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This exception happens when ClaimCenter detects that you have changed encryption schemes without properly leaving the old plugin registered.

You can have multiple plugins which implement the `IEncryption` interface.

Lets say you're using SHA1 encryption registered through a `SHA1Encryption.gwp` Plugin Registry:

```
<plugin
  interface="IEncryption"
  name="SHA1Encryption">
  <plugin-gosu
    gosuclass="com.mycompany.plugins.encryption.SHA1EncryptionPluginImpl"/>
</plugin>
```

And configured in `config.xml`:

```
<!-- The name of the current encryption plugin. -->
<param name="CurrentEncryptionPlugin" value="SHA1Encryption"/>
```

Then you decide to switch to AES encryption.

You first have to create a new Plugin Registry file `AESEncryption.gwp`:

```
<plugin
  interface="IEncryption"
  name="AESEncryption">
  <plugin-gosu
    gosuclass="com.mycompany.plugins.encryption.AESEncryptionPluginImpl"/>
</plugin>
```

Then you have to modify the `config.xml` to tell ClaimCenter to use the new Plugin:

```
<!-- The name of the current encryption plugin. -->
<param name="CurrentEncryptionPlugin" value="AESEncryption"/>
```

Do not remove the `SHA1Encryption.gwp` Plugin Registry.

ClaimCenter keeps track of the Encryption Plugin used to encrypt each record, by *NAME* of the Plugin Registry file. If it can't find the file, you will get this error.

ClaimCenter is also capable of detecting that the implementation class has changed even if the plugin name hasn't (metadata change). In that case, it looks for a Plugin Registry named `OldEncryption.gwp`.

If it can't find the specific name, *AND* can't find `OldEncryption.gwp`, then you will get this error.

More information can be found in the Integration Guide from Guidewire.

Answer (score 0):

I found this was due to my not having the extensions.properties file updated to the latest number.  To fix:

- Hit Cntl-Shift-n
- Search for "extension.properties"
- Go into the file and change the number to the appropriate number
- Save
- Restart Guidewire Studio

I was set after I did this.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to pretend this type of exceptions,
change the DB path from **database-confix.xml**

Answer (score -1):

Whenever will get this UpgradeException, the newer upgrade version number shows in console along with old version number. You have to update the new number in 
 the extension.property file.